# Dropping words from a string in php

Tags: php, string, str-replace

i have a string

> showing 1 - 12 of 324 Results

i want to stip this string like

> 324 Results

or

> 324

only

Note that, 324 is figure that will change every time the string is obtained. it may be 2-figures (34), three or 4 figured.

currently i am at success only in droping showing word using code

```
'str_replace('Showing', '', $s)'
```

this gives out put as

> 1 - 12 of 324 Results

how can i use str_replace function to get my purpose? or i should use anyother function of PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use This So easy**

```
$exampleString = "showing 1 - 12 of 324 Results";
$arrayResult   =explode(" ",$exampleString);

//output will be 324,according to the index the result will change
echo $arrayResult[5];
```

Comment: great and simple answer without going into regex(tough for me to understand), thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

You could use `preg_match()`.

```
preg_match('/(?P<results>\d+)\sResults$/', $str, $matches);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/soXaqU).

Then examine `$matches['results']` for the number of results or `$matches[0]` for the number of results and the `' Results'` substring.

Comment: 'str_replace('Showing', '', $s)' is replaced by 'preg_match('/(?P<results>\d+)\sResults$/', $str, $matches)'returns empty

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
preg_replace('~^.*?(\d+\s+Results)$~i', '$1', 'showing 1 - 12 of 324 Results');
```

OR

```
preg_match('~\d+\s+Results$~i', 'showing 1 - 12 of 324 Results', $m);
var_dump ( $m[0] );
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to split the strings at `" of "` and again at `" Results"`.

```
$temp = explode(' of ', $yourString);
$temp2 = explode(' Results', $temp[1]);
$totalResults = $temp2[0];
```

You can also use `preg_match()` as alex suggested, which is a more 'elegant' solution as it is done with one function call but may be difficult to understand if you are not familiar with regex.

Comment: thanks to everyone here for helping me and getting me things done..to all of you

Answer (score 0):

Alex's answer is good, maybe a regular expression needs more time to understand. You can explode the string and just get the element before the last one.

```
$arr = explode(' ', 'showing 1 - 12 of 324 Results');
$number = $arr[count($arr)-2];
```

This way you will get the number of total results. And whenever you want you can add the 'Results' word. Don't forget to `trim()` the string before the `explode()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

check this :

```
$result = "showing 1 - 12 of 324 Results";
$buffer = substr( $result , strpos( $result , "of") + 2 , strlen($result));
//$buffer is : 324 Results

$buffer = explode(" ", $buffer);

// you have to block 1 : $buffer[0] ~ '324' AND 2 : $buffer[1] : 'result'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = explode('of', $str);
$results = (int)$results[1];
```